# Label in traditionalform with text

Tags: text, traditional-form

I want to have a figure with a label x_P, in style of LaTeX,

```
TraditionalForm[Style[Subscript[x, P], FontSize -> 24]]
```

But

```
Plot[x^2 + 50, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 150}}, Epilog -> 
    Text[TraditionalForm[Style[Subscript[x, P], FontSize -> 18]], {1, 45}]]
```

The command Text changes the x into a different style again.

[image]

Comment: Documentation for `Text` states that the `TraditionalForm ` is the default for `Text` when used in graphics, and the example shown is consistent with the plot in this question.  Nonetheless, the result is different from that produced by `TraditionalForm[Style[Subscript[x, P], FontSize -> 24]]`, as shown in the question.  Perhaps, it is supposed to be different, but I can find no statement to that effect in  the documentation.

Comment: The default `FontFamily` for the `Plot` appears to be `"Helvetica"`; whereas, the general default is `"Times"`. Use `Text[TraditionalForm[Style[Subscript[x, P], FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]], {1, 45}]`